# Handling errors for replaying, long-living Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs6

**StackBlitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s8mzka

I have an Angular template that subscribes to an Observable using the `async` pipe. This Observable is created by:

1. Subscribing to an NgRx Store Selector (that gives us selected user filters)
2. Switch-mapping to an API request with the selected user filters
3. Performing several operatos like `map`, `filter` etc. after the `switchMap`
4. The steps 2 and 3 could repeat any amount of times

The API request in `switchMap` can fail for several reasons, which might produce an error notification.

We want to handle that error by showing an error alert. This error alert should also be shown by subscribing to an Observable using the `async` pipe. This angry-path Observable should directly derive from the happy-path Observable without the use of intermediate Subjects or any other side effects.

Problems we've encountered with proposed solutions:

- `catchError` or `materialize` inside `switchMap`: Wrapping the error in another object changes the data structure of the notification and makes using the following filters like `map`, `filter` etc. very hard. Operators like `debounceTime` or `delay` can't immediately forward the error because it's treated as a `next` notification.
- `retry`: Given that the source Observable is a replaying Subject, this will trigger a new API call on every re-subscribe, leading to an endless loop if the server keeps responding with errors. Also, we can't really forward the error notification using `retry`.
- Dispatching actions, nexting a Subject or setting `this.error` inside a `tap`: Creating side effects like that for a trivial use-case like this seems unnecessary and go against functional design principles.

**product.service.ts**

```
getProducts$() {
  return this.store.select(selectProductFilters).pipe(
    switchMap(filters => this.http.get("/api/products?" + encodeFilters(filters))
    // ... map, filter, delay
  );
}
```

**products.component.ts**

```
products$: Observable<Product[]>
error$: Observable<string>

ngOnInit() {
  this.products$ = this.productService.getProducts$();
  
  this.error$ = this.products$.pipe(
    // what can we do here to get errors as notifications
  );
}
```

**products.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="(products$ | async) as products">{{products | json}}</div>
<div class="error" *ngIf="(error$ | async) as error">{{error}}</div>
```

So the question is:

How can we create two Observables for our template: One that emits `next` notifications and one that emits `error` notifications while keeping the source Observable alive after errors?

**EDIT**

We're looking for a very general solution for this - the above example uses just one `switchMap`, but the solution should be applicable for any Observable pipeline. For example, imagine the Service looked like this:

**product.service.ts**

```
getProducts$() {
  return this.store.select(selectProductFilters).pipe(
    switchMap(filters => this.http.get("/api/products?" + encodeFilters(filters))
    // ... map, filter, delay
    switchMap(...)
    // ... map, filter, delay
    switchMap(...)
  );
}
```

The solution should be able to handle errors in any of these `switchMap` statements and propagate them to the template.

Comment: Can't you simply subscribe the observable in your component and handle the errors there?

Comment: That would also unsubscribe from the source observable after the first error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be my approach:

#### product.service.ts

```js
getProducts$(): Observable<Product[] | { hasError: boolean }> {
  return this.store$.pipe(
    switchMap(
      filters => this.httpClient.get("/api/products?" + encodeFilters(filters)).pipe(
        catchError(err => of({ hasError: true, msg: 'an error' })),
      )
    ),
    share(),
  )
}
```

#### products.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const [products$, errors$] = partition(this.productService.getProducts$(), (v: any) => !v.hasError);

  this.products$ = products$.pipe(
    filter(products => products.length > 0),
    map(products => products.map(product => ({name: product.name.toUpperCase(), price: product.price + ",00 €"}))),
    delay(300)
  );

  this.products$ = merge(this.products$, errors$.pipe(mapTo(null)));
  this.error$ = merge(this.products$.pipe(mapTo(null)), errors$);
}
```

It's important that we use `share()` in `getProducts()`. What it does is to place a `Subject` instance between the data consumers and the data producer. It is required as inside the component's `ngOnInit` there will be multiple subscriptions to the same source(everything above `share()`).

The `partition` will subscribe to the provided `source` [twice](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/partition.ts#L55-L58), once for each part.

Then,

```js
this.products$ = merge(this.products$, errors$.pipe(mapTo(null)));
this.error$ = merge(this.products$.pipe(mapTo(null)), errors$);
```

makes sure that if we have some products displayed and an error occurs afterwards, only the error will be shown and vice versa.

---

You might be wondering now, aren't there too many subscribers? I'd say no. The `Subject` I've mentioned above will have 5 subscribers. Let's see why.

```html
<div *ngIf="(products$ | async) as products">{{products | json}}</div>
```

will subscribe to `merge(this.products$, errors$.pipe(mapTo(null)));`, so we have 2 subscribers.

Then,

```html
<div class="error" *ngIf="(error$ | async) as error">{{error}}</div>
```

will subscribe to  `merge(this.products$.pipe(mapTo(null)), errors$).pipe(debounceTime(0));`, but the first argument is the first `merge(...)`, so it will mean another 2 subscribers, plus `errors$`, so a total of 5 subscribers.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jemhog?file=src%2Fproducts%2Fproducts.component.ts).

---

### Edit

Another approach:

#### product.service.ts

```js
getProducts$(): Observable<Product[] | { hasError: boolean }> {
  return this.store$.pipe(
    switchMap(filters => this.httpClient.get("/api/products?" + encodeFilters(filters))),
    filter(products => products.length > 0),
    map(products => products.map(product => ({name: product.name.toUpperCase(), price: product.price + ",00 €"}))),
    delay(300),

    tap({ next: () => console.log('next notif'), error: () => console.log('error notif') }),

    // we want to catch the error and pass it along with the `hasError` flag
    // so that it can be intercepted by the `error$` stream
    // at this point, the source (`store$`) is unsubscribed
    // and that's why we use `throwError`, so that `retryWhen` can intercept it and eventually
    // **re-subscribe** to the source, but only when it has something new to emit, otherwise
    // we might run into an infinite loop 
    catchError(err => concat(of({ hasError: true, msg: err }), throwError(err))),
    
    // `skip(1)` - we want to skip the error from which an error resulted
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(switchMapTo(this.store$.pipe(skip(1))))),
    
    // using it because `partition` subscribes **twice** to the source
    share(),
  )
}
```

#### products.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const [products$, errors$] = partition(this.productService.getProducts$(), (n) => !(n as any).hasError);

  this.products$ = products$ as  Observable<Product[]>;;
  this.error$ = errors$;
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rft4jt?file=src%2Fproducts%2Fproducts.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks for this approch. Yeah moving out the operators to the component solves a few issues - it's just that we really want to keep the "business logic" inside the service for decoupling and reusability reasons. But I guess you could already partition and re-merge the two streams inside the service...

Comment: There is just one challange, I guess I'd need to extend the example for that. Let's say we need to call another API after the `filter`, `map` and `delay`. With the proposed approach we'd need to share, partition and re-merge after every potential error source. I'm really looking for a way to fully utilize the RxJS `error` notification until right before the template.

Comment: Makes sense. You should've mentioned this case beforehand :D. So you might have a stream where multiple API calls occur, but you want to derive from this entire stream another stream that is responsible for displaying the errors. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry that it wasn't clearly described that way in my post.

Comment: No worries! It's an interesting problem anyways

Comment: @ggradnig just added another approach!

Comment: Hey, great idea concatting an error after the notification to trigger retry - haven't thought of that! Also very good idea to use the store as a notifier for retry. Thank you!

Comment: I’m glad I could help!